# How can I hide (slide down basically) the Button (which is aligned at the bottom) whenever the recycle view is scrolled in android studio using java

Tags: java, android, xml

I know how it can be applied to the toolbar w.r.t. any scrollView in Coordinator layout.
I wanna do the same thing with the button w.r.t. RecycleView.
Just like the bottomNav in the app Pinterest.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way that comes to mind is to use the **TranslateAnimation** provided by Android and to check if the RecyclerView is being scrolled. Here is what you need to do

1. Add a scroll listener to the RecyclerView and check if the scrolling direction is downward or upward

   ```
   YourRecyclerView.addScrollListener(new ScrollListener() {
       someScrollListenerMethod() {
           if (scrolling up) {
               showButton();
           } else {
               hideButton();
           }
        }
   );
   ```
2. Create an animation for sliding the button up and down.

   ```
   slideDownAnimation = TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 0f, ScreenHeight)
   slideDownAnimation.duration = 1000f //1 second

   slideUpAnimation = TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, ScreenHeight, 0f)
   slideUpAnimation.duration = 1000f //1 second
   ```
3. Create the show and hide button methods which will show and hide the button

   ```
   private void showButton() {
       yourButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
       yourButton.startAnimation(slideUpAnimation);
   }

   private void hideButton() {
       yourButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE;
       yourButton.startAnimation(slideDownAnimation);
   }
   ```

Just a note, the code shared in step 1 is not the actual library code (I could not remember the exact code) but you can easily find it out.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the applied code as explained by Bilal. Just in case anybody need it,

```
  private void buttonSlideAnimation() {
            addButton = findViewById(R.id.bottom_add_button);

            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

            final TranslateAnimation slideDownAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 0f, height);
            final TranslateAnimation slideUpAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, height, 0f);
            slideDownAnimation.setDuration(1000);
            slideUpAnimation.setDuration(1000);


            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                }

                @Override
                public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                    if (dy>0){
                        addButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        addButton.startAnimation(slideDownAnimation);
                    } else {
                        addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        addButton.startAnimation(slideUpAnimation);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
```